# 500 Error - Unable to select and perform a post action

Tags: winforms, asp.net-web-api

I am not good with Web API. Here is my problem. I send an Json serialized object from my Windows Form Application. The object is an Entity table. When I  do a get response it returns a 500 server error. Basically I plan to have multiple post methods in one controller which I may not be doing right. So I need you guys to guide me on what I have been doing wrong.

Here is my Controller:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(HttpWebResponse)), HttpPost, ActionName("MerchandiseApi")]        
public HttpResponseMessage PostMain(IList<IMF_Main> mainFromConsolidator)
{
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 2);

            using (var anthill = new AnthillConsolidatorEntities())
            {
                var main = new IMF_Main();
                foreach (var item in mainFromConsolidator)
                {
                    main.BrandID = item.BrandID;
                    main.ItemID = item.ItemID;
                    main.CategoryID = item.CategoryID;
                    main.SubCategoryID = item.SubCategoryID;
                    main.ClassID = item.ClassID;
                    main.GenderID = item.GenderID;
                    main.CoaID = item.CoaID;
                    main.SubCoaID = item.SubCoaID;
                    main.First_SRP = item.First_SRP;
                    main.Current_SRP = item.Current_SRP;
                    main.Previous_SRP = item.Previous_SRP;
                    main.isSenior = item.isSenior;
                    main.isActive = item.isActive;
                    main.DateCreated = item.DateCreated;
                    anthill.IMF_Main.Add(main);
                    anthill.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 1); 
}
```

Here's my WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "MerchandiseApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
        }
```

Here is where the Uri gets built: I have 2 more tables to send but I will start with this. This goes to my first Post method to the server

```
var jsonMain = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(consolidatorEntities.IMF_Main, Formatting.None);
HttpPost("http://localhost:50826/api/Merchandise/PostMain", jsonMain) == 1.ToString()

    public string HttpPost(string uri, string json)
            {
                string content = "";
                try
                {
                    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.Accept = "application/json";
                    request.ContentType = "application/json";

                    byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                    request.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
                    request.GetRequestStream().Close();

                    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncod

ing("UTF-8"));
                content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error sending data to Anthill \nException: " + ex, "Monytron - Consolidator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            return content;
        }
```

Comment: I plan to add more Post methods for the other 2 entities that will be sent to this same controller but I'm not sure how I would tell my client what post action to send the object to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The main problem is with your routing. Routes will check in order so when you post a request to `http://localhost:50826/api/Merchandise/PostMain` and you have these routes in order:

1. `"api/{controller}/{id}"`
2. `"api/{controller}/{action}"`

So the first route will match:

- If your `PostMain` method is the only action with `[HttpPost]`, then `mainFromConsolidator` will be null in your `foreach` loop you will receive a `NullReferenceException` that result in a 500 error.
- If you have multiple method decorated with [HttpPost], then the call is ambiguous between those actions and you will receive an `InvalidOperationExpception` with "Multiple actions were found that match the request" message that result in a 500 error.

The other problem is you are using an `ActionName("MerchandiseApi")` but didn't post to that action.

**Solution**

You can use multiple solutions. As an option you can define only one route:

- `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`

This way you can create a controller that contains actions like these:

```
public class SomeController
{

    // matches GET /api/some/action1  
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Action1()

    // matches GET /api/some/action2/5
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Action2(int id)

    // matches POST /api/some/action3
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Action3(SomeType someParameter)

    // matches POST /api/some/action4
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Action4(SomeType someParameter)
}
```

Anyway if you decide to define multiple routes, pay attention that routes will match in order and also if you used `ActionName` attribute, then use that name in url to call that action.

Comment: Hi @Reza, Sorry for the late reply and thank you for the answer. I understand the routing now but do I need to change anything with my URI or my winform application to use -- let's say, Action3()? Yes, I will be sending more URIs to this controller and I need to tell them to use either Action2() or Action1()

Comment: Hi@JoshuaMasangcay, You're welcome:) To call multiple actions from your winforms application, just create mutiple actions in your web api and call them using suitable url. For example to call `Action3` of `SomeController`, post a request to "http://localhost:50826/api/some/action3" and. Also keep in mind it's better to use `http://localhost:50826` as a setting, so you can simply change the url if you need.

Comment: Thank you, very much @Reza again. I have learned a lot. You have a wonderful day!

Comment: You are welcome :) you too, have a nice day. By the way if you find the answer helpful, you can kindly accept and upvote the answer :)